# How to batch refactor old multi-line C string into C++11 raw string literal

Tags: c++, c++11, refactoring, rawstring

I have some legacy code with old style C string.

```
string foo = "blah blah1"
             "blah blah2"
             "blah blah3"
             "blah blah4";
```

I want to convert all of them into C++11 raw string literal.

```
string foo = R"(
    blah blah1
    blah blah2
    blah blah3
    blah blah4
)";
```

Is there some tool/editor/script I can use to batch convert them?

I understand that those two versions are different(the first `foo` does not have line break, but in my case, I don't care about `\n`, so they are equivalent.

Comment: Note that the 2 versions are not equivalent. `"blah blah1blah blah2blah blah3blah blah4"` vs multiline

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. In my case, they are equivalent.

Comment: @Yakk, I want to convert the first `foo` to the second `foo`. Why do you think my example does not match my problem?

Comment: @Yakk, yes, the example I gave is exactly what I want. I don't care about white space or line break.

Comment: I doubt that there is an existing tool to do this, but you could write your own using any language that will do a find and replace with regex.